# Extracting a value from a webpage

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

Good day - I am sure this was addressed numerous times, but I am frustrated I tried all possible ways and still cant get it to work.

I am trying to scrape a value from a website which has the following code:
[image]

I need to extract only 169.23

This is my code which is not working:

```
Sub ImportCurrentPrice2()

    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    Visible = True

    With appIE
    .navigate "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=AAPL"
    .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("hilite")

    Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(4).innerHTML

    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing
    Range("A1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

This returns an error.

Any suggestion how code above needs to be modified?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and find the value in your sheet.

```
Sub ImportCurrentPrice2()
    Dim appIE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim item_data As Object

    With appIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=AAPL"
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Set item_data = html.queryselector(".pr span")
    [A1] = item_data.innerText

    appIE.Quit
End Sub
```

OR:

```
Set item_data = html.getElementsByClassName("pr")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0)
[A1] = item_data.innerText
```